# Kendo scatter chart not showing proper date format

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using a kendo scatter chart with pan and zoom option and locale setting. I have set locale as bg-BG and when I zoom in or zoom out the date/ time format not working correctly.

For example for bg-BG  Month'year  format is coming properly which is proper.
When I zoom in the format changes to  month/day format which is not correct as per locale.
Zoom in again the format changes to HH:mm which is again wrong according to lcale format,

[Here is the fiddle with the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/vcszgfsy/)

I set locale in this way

```
  kendo.culture('bg-BG');
```

If the kendo chart does not fit tomlocale then it should not work for first time itself.
Any help is appreaciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If kendo shows you wrong date formats you can chceck date patterns for your language like this:

```
kendo.culture('bg-BG');   
console.log(kendo.culture());
```

And then if you wanna explicitly set date patterns in your chart do it like so:

```
...
categoryAxis: {
    labels: {
        dateFormats: {
            minutes: culture.calendar.patterns.T,
            hours: culture.calendar.patterns.g,
            days: culture.calendar.patterns.d,
            weeks: culture.calendar.patterns.d,
            months: "MM" + culture.calendar['/'] + "yyyy",
            years: "yyyy"
        },
    },
....
```